# How to set an upper limit for waiting for a socket.on event?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timer, socket.io

I trigger an event

```
socket.emit('release now');
```

which after some time may or may not trigger another event back (depending on some user input).

```
socket.on('released', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

But I only want to wait for a maximum, say, 5 seconds. And if not, then carry on with `//do stuff` anyway (with some other minor things changed).

How do I do this with `setTimeout`?, or should I be using it in the first place? Because I can't think of how to have them (`socket.on('...` and `seTimeout`) communicate with each other....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you're after but Ill take a shot:

```
var eventTimeout = setTimeout(function{ /* timeout code here */}, 5000);
socket.emit('release now'); // emit fired and timer set

socket.on('released', function() {
   clearTimeout(eventTimeout); // cancel our timeout since we got released on time
   // do Stuff
});
```

So the

```
/* timeout code here */
```

Will fire if the released event does not happen within 5 seconds.

Comment: Nice. I forgot `clearTimeout` exists for this. One problem still though: If the `'released'` event still fires anwyays after the `setTimeout` then  `/* timeout code */` and `// do Stuff` both will be executed. Anyway around that?

Comment: You could use another flag to determine if your timeout code has fired yet or not. This kind structure can usually be avoided by redesigning your application to be more _'async'_

Comment: Could you point me to somwhere I could see in detail what you mean?

Comment: For the flag: `var released = false;` set this to true in your released handler and then check it in your timeout code.
A nice article I found on asynchronous javascript is <http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript>